# How to detect the this.select () event of the onfocus?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code to admit decimals:

```html
    <input id="precio" type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select();" onkeypress="return OnlyDecimal(event, '0.0', 4, 2);"/>

    <script>
     function OnlyDecimal(e, valInicial, nEntero, nDecimal) {
            var obj = e.srcElement || e.target;
            var key_code = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            var key_val = String.fromCharCode(key_code);
            var patron2 = /[\d.]/;
            var control = (key_code === 46 && (/[.]/).test(obj.value)) ? false : true;
            var existePto = (/[.]/).test(obj.value);
            //el tab
            if (key_code === 8)
                return true;

            if (valInicial !== obj.value) {
                var TControl = obj.value.length;
                if (existePto === false && key_code !== 46) {
                    if (TControl === nEntero) {
                        obj.value = obj.value + ".";
                    }
                }

                if (existePto === true) {
                    var subVal = obj.value.substring(obj.value.indexOf(".") + 1, obj.value.length);

                    if (subVal.length >= nDecimal) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return patron2.test(key_val) && control;
            }
            else {
                if (valInicial === obj.value) {
                    obj.value = '';
                }
                return patron2.test(key_val) && control;
            }
        }
      </script>
```

[image]

But when it's at the maximum number of digits allowed and with focus selected, it doesn't allow me to enter numbers to replace the one in the input.

Is there a way to validate this? or how to detect when the input is selected to validate it ?.
The goal is to be able to enter digits in the input when everything is selected. Is there any idea or solution? Is it explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` like below, if that is what you want

```html
<input id="precio" type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select();" onkeypress="return OnlyDecimal(event, '0.0', 4, 2);"/>

<script>
 function OnlyDecimal(e, valInicial, nEntero, nDecimal) {
        var obj = e.srcElement || e.target;
        var key_code = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        var key_val = String.fromCharCode(key_code);
        var patron2 = /[\d.]/;
        var control = (key_code === 46 && (/[.]/).test(obj.value)) ? false : true;
        var existePto = (/[.]/).test(obj.value);
        
        var haveSelection = obj.selectionEnd - obj.selectionStart;
        
        //el tab
        if (key_code === 8)
            return true;

        if (valInicial !== obj.value) {
            var TControl = obj.value.length;
            if (existePto === false && key_code !== 46) {
                if (TControl === nEntero) {
                    obj.value = obj.value + ".";
                }
            }

            if (existePto === true) {
                var subVal = obj.value.substring(obj.value.indexOf(".") + 1, obj.value.length);

                if (subVal.length >= nDecimal && !haveSelection) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return patron2.test(key_val) && control;
        }
        else {
            if (valInicial === obj.value) {
                obj.value = '';
            }
            return patron2.test(key_val) && control;
        }
    }
  </script>
```